# getExternalFilesdir Fail

Tags: android, android-file

OnActivityCreated I'm doing:

```
activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

In logcat I get:

```
com.package W/ContextImpl﹕ Failed to ensure directory: /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.package/files/Pictures
```

This happens only on LOLLIPOP (MOTO G 2014), and everything is fine on KITKAT (Nexus 4). I've **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** on manifest.
What am I missing here? The storage is mounted and reachable via a file browsing app (like ES Explorer).

EDIT: Surprisingly the file is correctly created under the directory even if I get the warning reported above.

Comment: did you get any solution to this?

Comment: Nope. Well, not totally. Staying with this solution, I've had some bad reports from some users, but I can't have all physical devices to test it. Others users are fine. Please let me know if you solve/workaround this somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

and use this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Actually:

```
getExternalFilesDir()
```

It returns the path to files folder inside `/Android/data/com.package/files/Pictures` on your SD card. And there is no folder named `Pictures` inside it. So you are getting that error.

Comment: This way I get no warning but I'm not inside the private context of the app. I'd just like to know why I can't get the private folder to work....

Comment: I second what Jumpa said.  I need to be storing files inside App folder where they'd be deleted if user uninstall the app.  Is there a reason why getExternalFilesDir where it's more appropriate for a lot of applications?

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for Android 2.1 or after, use

```
getExternalFilesDir(String type)
```

Read carefully https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Also, you'll need to use this method or something similar

```
boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    // We can read and write the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
} else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    // We can only read the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
} else {
    // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
    //  to know is we can neither read nor write
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
}
```

then check if you can access the sdcard. As said, read the official documentation.

You must get to directory (a File object) from SD Card and Make your specific File path such as:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

Also need to give permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue on only one device. The android version was 5.1.1(api 22)
What I found in manifest the permission was added as follows.

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
```

I removed the maxSdkVersion limit and then the problem was resolved.

```
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I added the maxSdkVersion before because somewhere I read like this permission was required for APIs 18 or older but seems like that is not the case. It differs device by device.

If you have same permission settings in your manifest this might help you.